# Installing FFMPEG to generate thumbnail from video file on virtual hosting

Tags: php, ffmpeg

How do I install FFMPEG in virtual private hosting in Godaddy?

Comment: I don't see what the question has to do with programming, but you don't need to "install" anything. Just [download a `ffmpeg` binary](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as ffmpeg is a binary that has to be installed by a priviliged user in the system (not you, poor virtualhoster!) you have no access to folders beneath your home/username assigned path. Even if yo manage to copy it entirely alreary compiled it will not run from there. :(

Of course everybody will tell you this is not the place to ask that and that you need a virtual private server or ask godaddy for the price for that.

**Edit:** Maybe you could look into [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpvideotoolkit/)